# Angular: Can't read property of undefined while json-pipe shows property

Tags: angular, typescript

filter.ts

```
export interface Filter {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    tags: Array<Tag>;
}
```

tag.ts

```
export interface Tag {
    id: number;
    value: string;
}
```

filters.component.ts

```
export class FiltersComponent implements OnInit {
//Filter contains a list of tags
public filterList: Array<Filter>;
public selectedFilter: Filter;

constructor(private filterService: FiltersService) {
  this.filterList = new Array<Filter>();
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.filterService.getAllFilters().subscribe(filter => setTimeout(
    () => this.filterList.push(...filter), 2000
  ))
}

onSelect(f: Filter){
  if(f === this.selectedFilter){
    this.selectedFilter = null;
  }else{
    this.selectedFilter = f;
    console.log(this.selectedFilter);
  }
}
}
```

filters.component.html

```
  <div>
    <div class="left">
      <mat-list class="filter-list" *ngFor="let f of filterList"
                (click)="onSelect(f)">
        <span>
          {{f.id}}
        </span>
        <span>
          {{f.name}}
        </span>
      </mat-list>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <ng-container *ngIf="selectedFilter">
        {{selectedFilter | json}}
        <mat-list *ngFor="let tag of selectedFilter.tags"></mat-list>
        <span>
          {{tag.id}}
        </span>
        here
      </ng-container>

    </div>
  </div>
```

After that wall of code, here comes my problem:

I am trying to access the `{{tag.id}}` in the html. the `console.log(...)` shows me that the filter infact has atleast one tag, which is why the `ngFor` executes(not sure if that's the right word) the `{{tag.id}}`, however I'm still getting the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Since I am already using the `nfIf` to check that there infact is a `Filter` and I am already using `ngFor` to check for tags, I have absolutely no idea what I am doing wrong.

If it matters, both `Array<Filters>` and `Array<Tags>` are json arrays(showing them in html requires the `json`-pipe)

Comment: can you please provide a minimal reproduction in stackblitz

Comment: @MeikVtune You have to use `<span>{{tag.id}}</span>` inside of `*ngFor` loop tag

Comment: @Abhishek And here I thought I've looked for the obvious errors, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
<mat-list *ngFor="let tag of selectedFilter.tags"></mat-list>
```

Your `mat-list` ends here and the `span` where you're using `tag.id` is below that. Hence it's `undefined`.

Restructure your `mat-list`'s end tag somehow to include the `span` inside the `mat-list`. Something like this:

```
<div>
  <div class="left">
    <mat-list class="filter-list" *ngFor="let f of filterList" (click)="onSelect(f)">
      <span>
          {{f.id}}
        </span>
      <span>
          {{f.name}}
        </span>
    </mat-list>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <ng-container *ngIf="selectedFilter">
      {{selectedFilter | json}}
      <mat-list *ngFor="let tag of selectedFilter.tags">
        <span>
          {{tag.id}}
        </span> here
      </mat-list>
    </ng-container>

  </div>
</div>
```